# Why Scala say type mismatch to a good definition?

Tags: scala

The code fragment,

```
  var line = Seq.empty[(String,Integer)]
  var fileCount : Int = -1   // good definition
  if (etc) 
      fileCount = tContSmry.getFileCount().toInt  // good cast
  line :+= ("etc", fileCount)  // where the error??
```

has this error:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Seq[(String, Any)]
required: Seq[(String, Integer)]
```

---

PS:  using Spark version 2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91, Scala version 2.11.8

Comment: Hint: what is the lowest common ancestor of `scala.Int` and `java.lang.Integer`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Int` is not `Integer`. You have `line: Seq[(String, Integer)]`, but you're trying to add `("etc", fileCount): (String, Int)` to it. The error message is a little weird, I'll give you that. `Integer` should almost never appear in your code; you should replace it with `Int`.

```
var line = Seq.empty[(String, Int)]
// side note: don't need a var here
val fileCount: Int = if(etc) tContSmry.getFileCount().toInt else -1
line :+= ("etc", fileCount)
```

Comment: In Scala 2.13, `line :+= ("etc", "2".toInt)` compiles and runs without an error.

Comment: @jrook Indeed. I presume OP is using 2.12 or older, since that does exhibit this behavior. I'm not entirely sure why that changed, especially since `Int` and `Integer` are apparently still different (try `implicitly[Int =:= Integer]`). Some dark magic is probably going on.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am using (edited question to say) Scala version 2.11.8